# Could not read JSON: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, jackson, resttemplate

I was trying to get the getAccessToken with spring rest template as given below. I am getting the below error, while calling oAuthRestTemplate.getAccessToken()

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
```

Code:

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();

resource.setAccessTokenUri("https://../oauth2/token");
resource.setUsername("u");
resource.setPassword("p");
resource.setClientSecret("...s");
resource.setClientId("...i");
resource.setGrantType("password");
List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>(2);
scopes.add("write");
scopes.add("read");
resource.setScope(scopes);


DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();

List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());  
messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
OAuth2RestTemplate oAuthRestTemplate =  new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource,clientContext);
oAuthRestTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

try {
    SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
    System.out.println(oAuthRestTemplate.getAccessToken());
    String result = oAuthRestTemplate.getForObject("url" + "/api/version", String.class);
} catch (RestClientException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Full Errortrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@44908881; line: 1, column: 159]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@44908881; line: 1, column: 159]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:491)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:454)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.java:47)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:142)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:216)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:168)
    at com.ClientTemplate.main(ClientTemplate.java:69)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@44908881; line: 1, column: 159]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1419)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:508)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._parseNumericValue(ParserBase.java:748)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.getLongValue(ParserBase.java:619)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessTokenJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2AccessTokenJackson2Deserializer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessTokenJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2AccessTokenJackson2Deserializer.java:44)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3051)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2206)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:168)
    ... 11 more
```

Tried without messageConverters.Still the same error.

Comment: Can you post the response?

Comment: Tried getting response `String result = oAuthRestTemplate.getForObject("url" + "/api/version", String.class);` .. But same error.

Comment: Did you try to call the url with any tool (Browser, wget, etc) and inspect the plain response?

Comment: I got the result in browser. But in the program oAuthRestTemplate.getAccessToken() itself is failing

Comment: Please post the response.

Comment: It is a valid json like `{
  "jiveVersion" : "8.0.3.1 ",
  "jiveCoreVersions" : [ {
    "version" : 2,
    "revision" : 3,
    "uri" : "/api/core/v2",
    "documentation" : "https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v2/rest"
  }, {
    "version" : 3,
    "revision" : 11,
    "uri" : "/api/core/v3",
    "documentation" : "https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/rest"
  } ],
  "instanceURL" : "https://url",
  "ssoEnabled" : [ "" ],
  "jiveEdition" : {
    "product" : "on-prem",
    "tier" : 0
  }
}` . Evenif i removed this service call,the code fails at .getAccessToken()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the look of your stacktrace I can suggest that you are using spring oauth version 1.0.1 which has this code inside `OAuth2AccessTokenJackson2Deserializer` at line 75:

```
...
else if (OAuth2AccessToken.EXPIRES_IN.equals(name)) {
    expiresIn = jp.getLongValue();
}
...
```

it expects field `expires_in` to be numeric. And your exception suggests that in your response it is in fact a `string`.

To fix this you can upgrade to latest version (2.1.1 at the moment) where they fixed this part to accept string value also:

```
....
else if (OAuth2AccessToken.EXPIRES_IN.equals(name)) {
    try {
        expiresIn = jp.getLongValue();
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        expiresIn = Long.valueOf(jp.getText());
    }
}
....
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. It generates the token. However, for the response `String result` it throws, `Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'throw': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN`

Comment: For my output response, I have a message before json starts... like `throw abcd; { }`

Comment: `throw abcd; { }` is not a valid JSON thus it gives you `JsonParseException`.

Comment: Got it. Some how can i change this to text instead of json?

Comment: Im not familiar with Oauth and i dont understand what are you trying to achieve with this reposnse, so i have no suggestions, sorry.

Comment: I just removed the message converter, for the time being and got it working. Thanks!